# How to query excluding conditional rows in Mysq

Tags: mysql

I have below mentioned tables:

Table1

```
ID     cat_id   Date                   key
IY-1   UTV-12   2018-03-18 15:04:25    xxt-14-yt
IY-2   UTV-12   2018-01-01 18:25:19    xxt-15-yt
IY-3   UTV-14   2018-03-05 13:12:14    xxt-17-yt
IY-4   UTV-15   2018-04-03 17:26:11    xxt-14-yt
```

Table2

```
Key         Value
xxt-14-yt   Pending
xxt-15-yt   Closed
xxt-17-yt   Open
```

In above table `cat_id` is unique id assigned for a particular category user, and `key` is mapped to status.

I want to fetch only those rows where any `cat_id` status is not equal to `Closed` status.

Required Output:

```
ID     cat_id   Date                   key
IY-3   UTV-14   2018-01-05 13:12:14    xxt-17-yt
IY-4   UTV-15   2018-07-03 17:26:11    xxt-14-yt
```

I am using below mentioned query but its not working properly.

Query:

```
select ID, cat_id, Date, key from Table1 t1
left join Table2 t2 on t1.key=t2.key
where t1.cat_id IN
(select cat_id from Table1 b1
left join Table2 b2 on b1.key=b2.key
where b2.Value!='Closed') and DATE(t1.Date)>='2018-03-01';
```

Comment: @jdigital Right, Because `UTV-12` is unique id on user based (i.e `IY-1` and `IY-2`) where request against one application is closed and one is pending, but I want to exclude those records.

Comment: What do you get when you run the query: SELECT t1.* FROM Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 on t1.key=t2.key WHERE t2.Value!='Closed'

Comment: @TanvirAhmed: That query wouldn't work when I put a date range, and only exclude `IY-2` but I want to exclude both `IY-1` and `IY-2` based on `cat_id`.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested it but I think it should work:

```
select * from table1 a 
left join 
    (select cat_id from table1 a 
        join table2 b on a.key = b.Key 
        where b.Value = 'Closed') 
    b on a.cat_id = a.cat_id
where b.cat_id is null
```

A more simple way would be:

```
 select * from table1
 where cat_id not in
    (select cat_id from table1 where key in
        (select key from table2 where Value = 'Closed'))
```

Answer (score 0):

from my understanding you want the only unique cat_id :

```
Select ID,cat_id,Date,key
From Table1
Where key IN (Select key from table2 where value <> 'Closed')
AND cat_id in (Select cat_id from 
                            (select cat_id,count(*) 
                             from table1 
                             group by cat_id 
                             having count(*)=1
                            ) 
               )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try inverting the selection:

```
SELECT ID, cat_id, Date, key FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.key=t2.key
WHERE t1.cat_id NOT IN
(SELECT cat_id FROM Table1 b1
 LEFT JOIN Table2 b2 ON b1.key=b2.key
 WHERE b2.Value='Closed');
```

This will exclude the two rows with UTV-12 since once of those rows is marked as closed:

Answer (score 0):

Please check with the following query:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.cat_id, t1.Date, t1.key FROM
 Table1 t1 
 LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.key=t2.key
WHERE t1.Date>='2018-03-01 00:00:00'
 AND t1.cat_id IN (select b1.cat_id FROM Table1 b1
 LEFT JOIN Table2 b2 ON b1.key=b2.key WHERE b2.Value!='Closed')
```